# Is this grammatical?

Tags: grammar, american-english, writing

> Could you tell us what's your favorite Google Chrome extensions? , The ones that you are using regularly and the ones that are cool no matter how much you use it or how popular it is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are unsure if this is grammatical?

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, and i want to post this in tech.  Facebook group, and i wana to be sure it's correct, grammatically or something else, is it?

Comment: Unless you are specific about what you think it wrong, this is a proofreading question, which is off-topic here. Please edit your question and explain what you suspect might be wrong with it.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know if it has something wrong with it or not, that's why i asked in the first place, if this off-topic here, can you lead me to the right place to post this kind of stuff ?

Comment: To assist you, both sentences are incorrect in matching subject with verb.

Comment: When you have enough reputation, this is something you can ask [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage), but as it is, this question won't offer anything to future visitors unless they happen to have the exact same sentence.

Comment: But I will offer: Could you tell us what your favorite Google Chrome extensions are? (subject-verb agreement) (no comma, why do you have a comma there?) Please include the ones that you are using regularly as well as the ones that are cool no matter how much you use them or how popular they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense to say it more like this:

*Please tell us which Google Chrome extension is your favorite, as well as which ones you use regularly. We would also like to know about the ones that you think are cool regardless of how often you use it or how popular it is.*

1. "Could you" can imply irritation or sarcasm; please sounds more polite
2. In english, the accepted syntax of a sentence is Subject-Verb-Object

   This case is called a Predicate-Nominative, where the object is the same as the subject(something is something)

   So it makes sense to say "Google Chrome Extension is your favorite."
3. We then add on another object seperating with a comma

   ", as well as which ones you use regularly."
4. I made the last part a seperate sentence simply because the puuting all the information you had made the sentence somewhat long, and it helps in writing to break things up, just like in speech. I also used some synonyms to simplify it.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but , why not : "Please tell us which Google Chrome extension is **your** favorite" ?

Comment: It would be **your**. Sorry for the spelling error

Answer (score 0):

The grammatically correct sentences would be: Could you tell us **what are** your favorite Google Chrome extensions? The ones that you are using regularly and the ones that are cool no matter how much you use **them** or how popular **they are**. I have not gone into how the sentences could be rephrased to sound polite or become simple, because, I feel, that is beyond the scope of the present question.